# ipython notebook command in anaconda opens jupyter notebook?

Tags: installation, ipython

The following is the command and the result.

```
[Anaconda2] C:\Users\Gurminder>ipython notebook
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook`... continue in 5 sec. Press Ctrl-C to quit now.
[I 17:56:25.760 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Gurminder
[I 17:56:25.763 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 17:56:25.763 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 17:56:25.766 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

And the display on the browser looks like following:

[image]

Why is it launching jupyter when I am giving the command to launch ipython.

I have updated all the packages including ipython.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is on the [IPython website](https://ipython.org/#jupyter-and-the-future-of-ipython):

> IPython is a growing project, with increasingly language-agnostic
>   components. IPython 3.x was the last monolithic release of IPython,
>   containing the notebook server, qtconsole, etc. As of IPython 4.0, the
>   language-agnostic parts of the project: the notebook format, message
>   protocol, qtconsole, notebook web application, etc. have moved to new
>   projects under the name Jupyter. IPython itself is focused on
>   interactive Python, part of which is providing a Python kernel for
>   Jupyter.

In summary, what previously was known as the IPython notebook now is the Jupyter notebook. Apart from the name, they are practically the same.

It even says so in the warning message you get:

> ```
> [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
> [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook`... continue in 5 sec. Press Ctrl-C to quit now.
> ```

`ipython notebook` is deprecated and you should use `jupyter notebook` instead, but IPython plays nice and runs the Jupyter notebook for you.

Comment: ok but even after updating all the modules in anaconda why is it displaying jupyter in such disoriented format?

Comment: I do not know. Have you tried a different browser? It looks like a stylesheet is missing, or the page did not fully load, or the browser blocks something... (I was not aware that this was part of the question.)

Comment: jupyter notebook gives a crash: OSError: [Errno None not found] 2

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thank you!

Comment: But how can we launch pyspark in interactive shell (like in ipython CLI) with this new version?
Like for instance in the earlier version, 
`IPYTHON=1 pyspark`
launches pyspark in ipython CLI

`IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark`
launches pyspark in Jupyter notebook

How can I get back ipython CLI if I want to?

Comment: @DeepakJanyavula I have no idea about pyspark. Maybe you can find your answer in [this post](https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f). Otherwise, consider asking this as a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).